# share anaconda folder between different Linux installation

Tags: linux, conda, archlinux, fedora-25, miniconda

On my laptop I have two Linux distribution installed: `Fedora 25` and `Arch`.
For purpose of saving disk space I would like to use only one instance of `Miniconda` shared between these two installation.

Question: Is such solution safe or are there any known problems that can occur in such situation?

---

## Update

It seems that there should be no problem with that: [Google Group Thread](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!searchin/anaconda/share$20anaconda$20installation$20between$20two$20different$20Linux$20distribution/anaconda/OrlwBfPmmKQ/p168XTN5BAAJ)

Comment: I expect the answer is no, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256504/40481